# Jackson - Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: kotlin, jackson, data-class

I'm trying to get some data from my back with a HTTP request and mapping it as a MutableList of my model.

The code is the exact same in 2 situations but one of them isn't working, and I've got an error for the first time? I've searched for it on Google but all the code examples are really different from mines and so are the solutions.

This is the error that I've got:

```
D/OkHttp: Callback failure for call to http://10.0.2.2:5000/...
D/OkHttp: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
D/OkHttp:  at [Source: (String)"{"recurrenceId":1,"meetingId":4,"weekDay":21}"; line: 1, column: 1]
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1139)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1093)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:332)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:265)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
D/OkHttp:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3023)
D/OkHttp:     at fr.intech.neith.api.RecurrenceApi.toDo(RecurrenceApi.kt:34)
        at fr.intech.neith.helpers.ApiHelper$GET$1.onResponse(ApiHelper.kt:35)
D/OkHttp:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
D/OkHttp:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is my data class:

```
package fr.intech.neith.models

data class Recurrence(val recurrenceId: Int = 0,
                      val meetingId: Int = 0,
                      val weekDay: Array<Int> = arrayOf())
```

And this is my API that makes the GET request:

```
    package fr.intech.neith.api

import...

class RecurrenceApi(context: Context): IOnApiResponse {
    var itodo: IToDoRecurrenceList? = null
    override fun toDo(body: String) {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()

        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        //val reader: ObjectReader = mapper.reader().forType(Meeting.class);
        val reader = mapper.readValue<MutableList<Recurrence>>(body)
        itodo!!.toExecuteR(reader)
    }

    var client = OkHttpClient()
    var api = ApiHelper(client, context)
    var url: String = "http://10.0.2.2:5000" + "/api/recurrence" // 192.168.43.135 4G - 10.0.2.2 ÉMULATEUR

    fun getRecurrenceList(meetingId: Int, cb: IToDoRecurrenceList) {
        val url2: String = url + "/${meetingId}";
        itodo = cb
        api.GET(url2, this)
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong here?

Here is a working example, totally similiar to the first because it works the same way:

```
package fr.intech.neith.models
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.*

data class Meeting(val hostFirstName: String = "",
                   val hostLastName: String = "",
                   val estimatedTime: String = "",
                   val startDate: Date = Date(),
                   val meetingId: Int = 0,
                   val name: String = "",
                   val hasEnded: Boolean = false,
                   val hostId: Int = 0,
                   val recurrence: Array<Int> = arrayOf(),
                   val index: Int = 0,
                   val isRecurrent: Boolean = false): Serializable

package fr.intech.neith.api


import android.content.Context
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
import fr.intech.neith.IOnApiResponse
import fr.intech.neith.IToDoList
import fr.intech.neith.helpers.*
import fr.intech.neith.models.Meeting
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient

class MeetingApi(context: Context): IOnApiResponse {
    var itodo: IToDoList<Meeting>? = null
    override fun toDo(body: String) {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()

        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        val reader = mapper.readValue<MutableList<Meeting>>(body)
        itodo!!.toExecute(reader)
    }

    var client = OkHttpClient()
    var api = ApiHelper(client, context)
    var url: String = "http://10.0.2.2:5000" + "/api/meeting" // 192.168.43.135 4G - 10.0.2.2 ÉMULATEUR

    fun getMeetingList(userId: Int, cb: IToDoList<Meeting>) {
        val url2: String = url + "/${userId}/names"
        itodo = cb
        api.GET(url2, this)
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT: This has solved the problem: `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)`

Answer (score 1):

From https://craftsmen.nl/kotlin-create-rest-services-using-jersey-and-jackson/ :

> In order to deserialize Kotlin data classes we have to register Jackson’s KotlinModule on an ObjectMapper instance.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

> Module that adds support for serialization/deserialization of Kotlin classes and data classes. Previously a default constructor must have existed on the Kotlin object for Jackson to deserialize into the object. With this module, single constructor classes can be used automatically, and those with secondary constructors or static factories are also supported.

Comment: I updated my post with a working example that looks exactly the same but that works. I think the problem is really little and that it should work the same way. I didn't look a lot at your links but it seems to be what I did here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't saw the  'com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue' import.

Comment: Show the json payloads.

Comment: After a little debug session, it seems that my request didn't get its answer, I'll fix that first.

Comment: (Sorry for the import, didn't show in the first example because there was too much)
I have a little asynchronous problem, by debugging and letting the request get its answer, I discovered a new error, I've edited my post.